# How to use rgamma to sample gamma in r?

Tags: r

If I want to sample Gamma(238, 10), why the code is

```
   theta <- rgamma(1000,238)/10
```

but not

```
  theta <- rgamma(1000,238, 10)
```

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The third argument to `rgamma` is `rate`, an inverse multiplicative scale parameter, so actually these two ways are equivalent:

```r
theta_1 <- rgamma(10000, 238, 10)
theta_2 <- rgamma(10000, 238) / 10

hist(theta_1)
```

[image]

```r
hist(theta_2)
```

[image]